# D3 smooth transitions for data updates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, websocket

I'm writing a web app that displays real-time audio spectrum using D3 to draw the graphs. Basically, the javascript receives a SPL value for each 1/3 octave bin graphing 32 points.  D3 does a good job updating at whatever interval I send data to it .  However, the changes in the graph look somewhat choppy because there are substantial changes in various parts of the spectrum between updates.  I'd like to find a way to smooth the changes.  Before I write something to delay a sample and do linear interpolation, is there a better way to do this? I prefer to compute this in the front-end as I'd rather not stream the interpolation data from the backend to reduce data load...

The update interval is dependent on the parameters selected including FFT size, sampling rate and averaging so I can't give an exact number however the data stream is coming at an interval in the range of 5ms to 10s....

Comment: Have you got a varying number of points in the line? If so I'd recommend looking at https://bocoup.com/blog/improving-d3-path-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Bostock wrote a great tutorial for updating line charts. There are several different approaches you can take:

1. Use d3's built-in path interpolator if the data is not time-series data and you want a smooth transition (use [Ian's link](http://bocoup.com/blog/improving-d3-path-animation) in the question comment, this is a good tutorial)
2. If it is time-series data, and you want the data to shift as it updates, you can add the new data point, redraw the line, slide it to the left, then remove the oldest datapoint:

```
// push a new data point onto the back
data.push(random());

// redraw the line, and then slide it to the left
path
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", null)
  .transition()
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ")");

// pop the old data point off the front
data.shift();
```

The detailed tutorial is here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/